# sand from under car animation

Tags: gimp, gif

I'm creating a mini game where you are driving a car in a desert. You're looking at the car from above. I already have a model for the car, but now I'm trying to create an animation of sand coming from under the wheels of the car. I've been trying to find a gif that I can modify with GIMP (by adding the car manually) but I couldn't find one. Since, I'm new to this I can't find an easy solution to this problem.

Does anyone here have any ideas on how to do this?

Here's the model of the car:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You’re probably after a [particle system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_system).

Many 3D tools have a particle system. If you’re using a Mac, Quartz Composer (a free app that’s part of Apple’s developer tools) might be what you’re after. It a very old and well established feature, so lots of applications have it.

Here’s something I made using Quartz Composer’s particle system.

[image: Particle System animation]

If you do a Google image search for `particle system animation`, the results probably look similar to what you’re after.

https://encrypted.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=particle%20emitter&tbs=imgo:1#tbs=imgo:1&tbm=isch&q=particle+system+animation

It’s pretty common for many games to run the particle system live in the game engine. That might also be an option.